# XPath - Get Sibling Value

Tags: xslt, xpath

For the following xml, what would be the xpath to:

1. Find the `<ContactTypeCode>` containing FPPRNO
2. Return the sibling value of `<ContactAddress>`

`<ContactDetails>
  <ContactDetail>
    <ContactTypeCode>EMAIL</ContactTypeCode>
    <ContactTypeText>Email Address</ContactTypeText>
    <ContactAddress>hpinfo@acme.co.uk</ContactAddress>
  </ContactDetail>
  <ContactDetail>
    <ContactTypeCode>FPPRNO</ContactTypeCode>
    <ContactTypeText>Fit and Proper Person Reg No.</ContactTypeText>
    <ContactAddress>AGE146</ContactAddress>
  </ContactDetail>
  <ContactDetail>
    <ContactTypeCode>PHONE</ContactTypeCode>
    <ContactTypeText>Phone</ContactTypeText>
    <ContactAddress>084892747291</ContactAddress>
  </ContactDetail>
</ContactDetails>`

Comment: *the sibling value of* what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below expression:

```
//ContactTypeCode[text()="FPPRNO"]/following-sibling::ContactAddress/text()
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it would be simpler not to follow your instructions verbatim and do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ContactDetails/ContactDetail[ContactTypeCode='FPPRNO']/ContactAddress"/>
```

This is assuming you want to use an absolute path. Depending on your context, you could use a relative path from your current node and make this even shorter.

---

P.S. It's best to avoid the `//` shortcut when the path can be specified explicitly.